# How to keep latest 1000 documents and delete rest in MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi all I have a mongo collection named products
I took distinct of products using
`db.getCollection('products').distinct("product.name")` - this gives me distinct of product name

But I want to delete the old documents for this distinct product and keep only latest 1000 documents

How to write a remove() query for this condition.

Comment: do you have timestamp attached to the doc? (e.g: `createdAt`)

Comment: yes @SaikatChakrabortty

Comment: can you share the sample document that you want for those 1000 documents?

Comment: Hi @VijayRajpurohit

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4525b352k454k5lk54454"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-05T11:04:41.916Z"),
    "product" : {
        "name" : "apple",
  "quantity" : "1kg"
    },
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4k2342jl25453453453353"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-05T11:00:02.242Z"),
    "product" : {
        "name" : "mango",
  "quantity" : "1kg"
    },
}

Answer (score 1):

Here I have created a query to get the latest 1000 distinct `product.name`

I have sorted on `_id` to get the latest documents.

please have a look:

```
db.sample.aggregate([
  {
    $sort:{
      "_id":-1
    }
  },
  {
    $group:{
      "_id":"$product.name",
      "date":{
        $first:"$date"
      },
      "id":{
        $first:"$_id"
      },
      "product":{
        $first:{
          "name":"$product.name",
          "quantity":"$product.quantity"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "_id":0,
      "_id":"$id",
      "date":1,
      "product":1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit:1000
  },
  {
    $out:"collection_name"
  }
])
```

This query will fetch the latest documents(distinct) and output will be written in a new collection `collection_name`

I have used `$out` for that.

**NOTE**

Handle the `$out` carefully because it will overwrite the collection.

For more about `$out` refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/).

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

One option: Copy the required/ filtered 1000 records to temp collection and drop the original collection then rename the temp collection to original collection and recreate any collection properties such as indexes etc. hth.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work db.collection.remove({"product.name":"apple"}).skip(1000)

Comment: no, it will not remove properly, As you mentioned it should be distinct as well.